# How to pass strip flag to linker in release mode in QBS?

Tags: qt, gcc, qbs

I'm using QBS 1.10.1 in Qt Creator 4.5.1 , under MSYS2.

I would like to pass `-s` to `g++` when invoked for the link step, to reduce the size of the release mode binary. How do I do this?

So far I have tried as suggested by the documentation:

```
   cpp.driverFlags: ["-municode", "-static", "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++"]

    Properties {
        condition: qbs.configuration === "Release"
        cpp.driverFlags: outer.concat("-s")
    }
```

however it does not actually pass the `-s` in Release mode, i.e. it's as if the Properties block were not there.

*Note:* The `cpp.driverFlags` option actually passes flags to all instances of `g++`, not just link steps; however I have been unable to find a way to only specify flags for the link step. The g++ is smart enough to ignore those flags if it wasn't a link step. The `cpp.linkerFlags` field actually transforms the flags to a `-Wl,"flag"` option which is not the right behaviour for these flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You should not test for the value of qbs.configuration, which is an arbitrary string set by users. Instead, use `qbs.buildVariant`, where `"release"` (all lower case!) is a known value.
2. `-s` is not a driver flag, but an actual linker flag, i.e. an option that `ld` understands. Therefore, you should use `cpp.linkerFlags`. The option will be automatically escaped if the gcc frontend is used for linking.

Comment: The `"release"` being in lower-case threw me off; in the Qt Creator it's consistently shown with the first letter capitalized.  Before I realized my error there, I also found that `condition: !qbs.debugInformation` worked.

Comment: Is there a way to make it complain if I use an undefined variable (as opposed to acting as if the variable exists as an empty value)

Comment: In what context?